# accessing 'blog' functionality / template in FUEL CMS

Tags: php, codeigniter, fuelcms

I'm having trouble getting the "stock" blog functionality / template working within FUEL CMS.

I have read that it is already there, stock with the download configuration of the CMS; I have also tried creating one from scratch and uploading a 'blog' theme from a project found in GitHub. None have worked so far.

I found the blog variable at:

```
_variables/global.php
```

I have created a 'blog' controller via interpretation of (gappy) docs.

By adding the below code within it; then making a corresponding 'blog.php' view. I get nothing but a **404 error**.

```
<?php

class Blog extends CI_Controller {

    public function view($page = 'home')
    {
      //you can acesse this http://example.com/blog/view/  
    }

    public function new($page = 'home')
    {
      //you can acesse this http://example.com/blog/new/   
    }


}
```

Within the modules folder. I found this 'stock' blog controller file. But don't know how to use it? found at: **/fuel/modules/blog/controller/blog.php**

```
<?php
require_once(MODULES_PATH.'/blog/libraries/Blog_base_controller.php');
class Blog extends Blog_base_controller {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

    }

    function _remap()
    {

        $year = ($this->uri->rsegment(2) != 'index') ? (int) $this->uri->rsegment(2) : NULL;
        $month = (int) $this->uri->rsegment(3);
        $day = (int) $this->uri->rsegment(4);
        $slug = $this->uri->rsegment(5);
        $limit = (int) $this->fuel->blog->config('per_page');

        $view_by = 'page';

        // we empty out year variable if it is page because we won't be querying on year'
        if (preg_match('#\d{4}#', $year) && !empty($year) && empty($slug))
        {
            $view_by = 'date';
        }
        // if the first segment is id then treat the second segment as the id
        else if ($this->uri->rsegment(2) === 'id' && $this->uri->rsegment(3))
        {
            $view_by = 'slug';
            $slug = (int) $this->uri->rsegment(3);
            $post = $this->fuel->blog->get_post($slug);
            if (isset($post->id))
            {
                redirect($post->url);
            }
        }
        else if (!empty($slug))
        {
            $view_by = 'slug';
        }

        // set this to false so that we can use segments for the limit
        $cache_id = fuel_cache_id();
        $cache = $this->fuel->blog->get_cache($cache_id);

        if (!empty($cache))
        {
            $output =& $cache;
        }
        else
        {
            $vars = $this->_common_vars();

            if ($view_by == 'slug')
            {
                return $this->post($slug);
            }
            else if ($view_by == 'date')
            {
                $page_title_arr = array();
                $posts_date = mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, $day, $year);
                if (!empty($day)) $page_title_arr[] = $day;
                if (!empty($month)) $page_title_arr[] = date('M', strtotime($posts_date));
                if (!empty($year)) $page_title_arr[] = $year;

                // run before_posts_by_date hook
                $hook_params = array('year' => $year, 'month' => $month, 'day' => $day, 'slug' => $slug, 'limit' => $limit);
                $this->fuel->blog->run_hook('before_posts_by_date', $hook_params);

                $vars = array_merge($vars, $hook_params);
                $vars['page_title'] = $page_title_arr;
                $vars['posts'] = $this->fuel->blog->get_posts_by_date($year, (int) $month, $day, $slug);
                $vars['pagination'] = '';
            }
            else
            {
                $limit = $this->fuel->blog->config('per_page');
                $this->load->library('pagination');
                $config['uri_segment'] = 3;
                $offset = $this->uri->segment($config['uri_segment']);
                $this->config->set_item('enable_query_strings', FALSE);
                $config = $this->fuel->blog->config('pagination');
                $config['base_url'] = $this->fuel->blog->url('page/');
                //$config['total_rows'] = $this->fuel->blog->get_posts_count();
                $config['page_query_string'] = FALSE;
                $config['per_page'] = $limit;
                $config['num_links'] = 2;

                //$this->pagination->initialize($config); 

                if (!empty($offset))
                {
                    $vars['page_title'] = lang('blog_page_num_title', $offset, $offset + $limit);
                }
                else
                {
                    $vars['page_title'] = '';
                }

                // run before_posts_by_date hook
                $hook_params = array('offset' => $offset, 'limit' => $limit, 'type' => 'posts');
                $this->fuel->blog->run_hook('before_posts_by_page', $hook_params);

                $vars['offset'] = $offset;
                $vars['limit'] = $limit;
                $vars['posts'] = $this->fuel->blog->get_posts_by_page($limit, $offset);

                // run hook again to get the proper count
                $hook_params['type'] = 'count';
                $this->fuel->blog->run_hook('before_posts_by_page', $hook_params);
                //$config['total_rows'] = count($this->fuel->blog->get_posts_by_page());
                $config['total_rows'] = $this->fuel->blog->get_posts_count();

                // create pagination
                $this->pagination->initialize($config); 
                $vars['pagination'] = $this->pagination->create_links();
            }

            // show the index page if the page doesn't have any uri_segment(3)'
            $view = ($this->uri->rsegment(2) == 'index' OR ($this->uri->rsegment(2) == 'page' AND !$this->uri->segment(3))) ? 'index' : 'posts';
            $output = $this->_render($view, $vars, TRUE);
            $this->fuel->blog->save_cache($cache_id, $output);
        }

        $this->output->set_output($output);
    }

    function post($slug = null)
    {
        if (empty($slug))
        {
            redirect_404();
        }

        $this->load->library('session');
        $blog_config = $this->fuel->blog->config();

        // run before_posts_by_date hook
        $hook_params = array('slug' => $slug);
        $this->fuel->blog->run_hook('before_post', $hook_params);

        $post = $this->fuel->blog->get_post($slug);

        if (isset($post->id))
        {
            $vars = $this->_common_vars();
            $vars['post'] = $post;
            $vars['user'] = $this->fuel->blog->logged_in_user();
            $vars['page_title'] = $post->title;
            $vars['next'] = $this->fuel->blog->get_next_post($post);
            $vars['prev'] = $this->fuel->blog->get_prev_post($post);
            $vars['slug'] = $slug;
            $vars['is_home'] = $this->fuel->blog->is_home();

            $antispam = md5(random_string('unique'));

            $field_values = array();

            // post comment
            if (!empty($_POST))
            {
                $field_values = $_POST;

                // the id of "content" is a likely ID on the front end, so we use comment_content and need to remap
                $field_values['content'] = $field_values['new_comment'];
                unset($field_values['antispam']);

                if (!empty($_POST['new_comment']))
                {
                    $vars['processed'] = $this->_process_comment($post);
                }
                else
                {
                    add_error(lang('blog_error_blank_comment'));
                }
            }

            $cache_id = fuel_cache_id();
            $cache = $this->fuel->blog->get_cache($cache_id);
            if (!empty($cache) AND empty($_POST))
            {
                $output =& $cache;
            }
            else
            {
                $this->load->library('form');

                if (is_true_val($this->fuel->blog->config('use_captchas')))
                {
                    $captcha = $this->_render_captcha();
                    $vars['captcha'] = $captcha;
                }
                $vars['thanks'] = ($this->session->flashdata('thanks')) ? blog_block('comment_thanks', $vars, TRUE) : '';
                $vars['comment_form'] = '';
                $this->session->set_userdata('antispam', $antispam);

                if ($post->allow_comments)
                {
                    $this->load->module_model(BLOG_FOLDER, 'blog_comments_model');
                    $this->load->library('form_builder', $blog_config['comment_form']);

                    $fields['author_name'] = array('label' => 'Name', 'required' => TRUE);
                    $fields['author_email'] = array('label' => 'Email', 'required' => TRUE);
                    $fields['author_website'] = array('label' => 'Website');
                    $fields['new_comment'] = array('label' => 'Comment', 'type' => 'textarea', 'required' => TRUE);
                    $fields['post_id'] = array('type' => 'hidden', 'value' => $post->id);
                    $fields['antispam'] = array('type' => 'hidden', 'value' => $antispam);
                    if (!empty($vars['captcha']))
                    {
                        $fields['captcha'] = array('required' => TRUE, 'label' => 'Security Text', 'value' => '', 'after_html' => ' <span class="captcha">'.$vars['captcha']['image'].'</span><br /><span class="captcha_text">'.lang('blog_captcha_text').'</span>');
                    }

                    // now merge with config... can't do array_merge_recursive'
                    foreach($blog_config['comment_form']['fields'] as $key => $field)
                    {
                        if (isset($fields[$key])) $fields[$key] = array_merge($fields[$key], $field);
                    }

                    if (!isset($blog_config['comment_form']['label_layout'])) $this->form_builder->label_layout = 'left';
                    if (!isset($blog_config['comment_form']['submit_value'])) $this->form_builder->submit_value = 'Submit Comment';
                    if (!isset($blog_config['comment_form']['use_form_tag'])) $this->form_builder->use_form_tag = TRUE;
                    if (!isset($blog_config['comment_form']['display_errors'])) $this->form_builder->display_errors = TRUE;
                    $this->form_builder->form_attrs = 'method="post" action="'.site_url($this->uri->uri_string()).'#comments_form"';
                    $this->form_builder->set_fields($fields);
                    $this->form_builder->set_field_values($field_values);
                    $this->form_builder->set_validator($this->blog_comments_model->get_validation());
                    $vars['comment_form'] = $this->form_builder->render();
                    $vars['fields'] = $fields;
                }

                $output = $this->_render('post', $vars, TRUE);

                // save cache only if we are not posting data
                if (!empty($_POST)) 
                {
                    $this->fuel->blog->save_cache($cache_id, $output);
                }
            }
            if (!empty($output))
            {
                $this->output->set_output($output);
                return;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            show_404();
        }
    }
    function _process_comment($post)
    {
        if (!is_true_val($this->fuel->blog->config('allow_comments'))) return;

        $notified = FALSE;

        // check captcha
        if (!$this->_is_valid_captcha())
        {
            add_error(lang('blog_error_captcha_mismatch'));
        }

        // check that the site is submitted via the websit
        if (!$this->_is_site_submitted())
        {
            add_error(lang('blog_error_comment_site_submit'));
        }

        // check consecutive posts
        if (!$this->_is_not_consecutive_post())
        {
            add_error(lang('blog_error_consecutive_comments'));
        }

        $this->load->module_model(BLOG_FOLDER, 'blog_users_model');
        $user = $this->blog_users_model->find_one(array('fuel_users.email' => $this->input->post('author_email', TRUE)));

        // create comment
        $this->load->module_model(BLOG_FOLDER, 'blog_comments_model');
        $comment = $this->blog_comments_model->create();
        $comment->post_id = $post->id;

        $comment->author_id = (!empty($user->id)) ? $user->id : NULL;
        $comment->author_name = $this->input->post('author_name', TRUE);
        $comment->author_email = $this->input->post('author_email', TRUE);
        $comment->author_website = $this->input->post('author_website', TRUE);
        $comment->author_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        $comment->content = trim($this->input->post('new_comment', TRUE));
        $comment->date_added = NULL; // will automatically be added

        //http://googleblog.blogspot.com/2005/01/preventing-comment-spam.html
        //http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spam_in_blogs

        // check double posts by IP address
        if ($comment->is_duplicate())
        {
            add_error(lang('blog_error_comment_already_submitted'));
        }

        // if no errors from above then proceed to submit
        if (!has_errors())
        {
            // submit to akisment for validity
            $comment = $this->_process_akismet($comment);

            // process links and add no follow attribute
            $comment = $this->_filter_comment($comment);

            // set published status
            if (is_true_val($comment->is_spam) OR $this->fuel->blog->config('monitor_comments'))
            {
                $comment->published = 'no';
            }

            // save comment if saveable and redirect
            if (!is_true_val($comment->is_spam) OR (is_true_val($comment->is_spam) AND $this->fuel->blog->config('save_spam')))
            {
                if ($comment->save())
                {
                    $notified = $this->_notify($comment, $post);
                    $this->load->library('session');
                    $vars['post'] = $post;
                    $vars['comment'] = $comment;
                    $this->session->set_flashdata('thanks', TRUE);
                    $this->session->set_userdata('last_comment_ip', $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
                    $this->session->set_userdata('last_comment_time', time());
                    redirect($post->url);
                }
                else
                {
                    add_errors($comment->errors());
                }
            }
            else
            {
                add_error(lang('blog_comment_is_spam'));
            }
        }
        return $notified;
    }

    // check captcha validity
    function _is_valid_captcha()
    {
        $valid = TRUE;

        // check captcha
        if (is_true_val($this->fuel->blog->config('use_captchas')))
        {
            if (!$this->input->post('captcha'))
            {
                $valid = FALSE;
            }
            else if (!is_string($this->input->post('captcha')))
            {
                $valid = FALSE;
            }
            else
            {

                $post_captcha_md5 = $this->_get_encryption($this->input->post('captcha'));
                $session_captcha_md5 = $this->session->userdata('comment_captcha');
                if ($post_captcha_md5 != $session_captcha_md5)
                {
                    $valid = FALSE;
                }
            }
        }
        return $valid;
    }

    // check to make sure the site issued a session variable to check against
    function _is_site_submitted()
    {
        return ($this->session->userdata('antispam') AND $this->input->post('antispam') == $this->session->userdata('antispam'));
    }

    // disallow multiple successive submissions 
    function _is_not_consecutive_post()
    {
        $valid = TRUE;

        $time_exp_secs = $this->fuel->blog->config('multiple_comment_submission_time_limit');
        $last_comment_time = ($this->session->userdata('last_comment_time')) ? $this->session->userdata('last_comment_time') : 0;
        $last_comment_ip = ($this->session->userdata('last_comment_ip')) ? $this->session->userdata('last_comment_ip') : 0;
        if ($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == $last_comment_ip AND !empty($time_exp_secs))
        {
            if (time() - $last_comment_time < $time_exp_secs)
            {
                $valid = FALSE;
            }
        }
        return $valid;
    }

    // process through akisment
    function _process_akismet($comment)
    {
        if ($this->fuel->blog->config('akismet_api_key'))
        {
            $this->load->module_library(BLOG_FOLDER, 'akismet');

            $akisment_comment = array(
                'author'    => $comment->author_name,
                'email'     => $comment->author_email,
                'body'      => $comment->content
            );

            $config = array(
                'blog_url' => $this->fuel->blog->url(),
                'api_key' => $this->fuel->blog->config('akismet_api_key'),
                'comment' => $akisment_comment
            );

            $this->akismet->init($config);

            if ( $this->akismet->errors_exist() )
            {               
                if ( $this->akismet->is_error('AKISMET_INVALID_KEY') )
                {
                    log_message('error', 'AKISMET :: Theres a problem with the api key');
                }
                elseif ( $this->akismet->is_error('AKISMET_RESPONSE_FAILED') )
                {
                    log_message('error', 'AKISMET :: Looks like the servers not responding');
                }
                elseif ( $this->akismet->is_error('AKISMET_SERVER_NOT_FOUND') )
                {
                    log_message('error', 'AKISMET :: Wheres the server gone?');
                }
            }
            else
            {
                $comment->is_spam = ($this->akismet->is_spam()) ? 'yes' : 'no';
            }
        }

        return $comment;
    }

    // strip out 
    function _filter_comment($comment)
    {
        $this->load->helper('security');
        $comment_attrs = array('content', 'author_name', 'author_email', 'author_website');
        foreach($comment_attrs as $filter)
        {
            $text = $comment->$filter;

            // first remove any nofollow attributes to clean up... not perfect but good enough
            $text = preg_replace('/<a(.+)rel=["\'](.+)["\'](.+)>/Umi', '<a$1rel="nofollow"$3>', $text);
//          $text = str_replace('<a ', '<a rel="nofollow"', $text);

            $text = strip_image_tags($text);

            $comment->$filter = $text;
        }
        return $comment;
    }

    function _notify($comment, $post)
    {
        // send email to post author
        if (!empty($post->author))
        {
            $config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;
            $this->load->library('email', $config);

            $this->email->from($this->fuel->config('from_email'), $this->fuel->config('site_name'));
            $this->email->to($post->author->email); 
            $this->email->subject(lang('blog_comment_monitor_subject', $this->fuel->blog->config('title')));

            $msg = lang('blog_comment_monitor_msg');
            $msg .= "\n".fuel_url('blog/comments/edit/'.$comment->id)."\n\n";

            $msg .= (is_true_val($comment->is_spam)) ? lang('blog_email_flagged_as_spam')."\n" : '';
            $msg .= lang('blog_email_published').": ".$comment->published."\n";
            $msg .= lang('blog_email_author_name').": ".$comment->author_name."\n";
            $msg .= lang('blog_email_author_email').": ".$comment->author_email."\n";
            $msg .= lang('blog_email_author_website').": ".$comment->author_website."\n";
            $msg .= lang('blog_email_author_ip').": ".gethostbyaddr($comment->author_ip)." (".$comment->author_ip.")\n";
            $msg .= lang('blog_email_content').": ".$comment->content."\n";

            $this->email->message($msg);

            return $this->email->send();
        }
        else
        {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }

    function _render_captcha()
    {
        $this->load->library('captcha');
        $blog_config = $this->config->item('blog');
        $assets_folders = $this->config->item('assets_folders');
        $blog_folder = MODULES_PATH.BLOG_FOLDER.'/';
        $captcha_path = $blog_folder.'assets/captchas/';
        $word = strtoupper(random_string('alnum', 5));

        $captcha_options = array(
                        'word'       => $word,
                        'img_path'   => $captcha_path, // system path to the image
                        'img_url'    => captcha_path('', BLOG_FOLDER), // web path to the image
                        'font_path'  => $blog_folder.'fonts/',
                    );
        $captcha_options = array_merge($captcha_options, $blog_config['captcha']);
        if (!empty($_POST['captcha']) AND $this->session->userdata('comment_captcha') == $this->input->post('captcha'))
        {
            $captcha_options['word'] = $this->input->post('captcha');
        }
        $captcha = $this->captcha->get_captcha_image($captcha_options);
        $captcha_md5 = $this->_get_encryption($captcha['word']);
        $this->session->set_userdata('comment_captcha', $captcha_md5);

        return $captcha;
    }

    function _get_encryption($word)
    {
        $captcha_md5 = md5(strtoupper($word).$this->config->item('encryption_key'));
        return $captcha_md5;
    }
}
```

My goal is:

**1.)** Enable 'Blog' Module / template / functionality and understand how I did it. I find the docs lacking, I'm also new at code igniter so that could be why. I just want the most basic way to do this for now.

And **2.)** I want to create a page 'from scratch' that resolves on the dashboard side as well. I have created pages in `/views/` but they resolve with that whole string `/fuel/application/views/page/` I want to create a normal page without all that in the URL. I have tried creating corresponding controllers even variables and haven't had much luck!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of FUEL CMS 1.0 the blog module is no longer bundled with the CMS by default. You would need to do the following:

1. Download & setup FUEL CMS per the install instructions here: https://github.com/daylightstudio/FUEL-CMS
2. Next, once you've got that up and running you can download & setup the blog module per the instructions here: https://github.com/daylightstudio/FUEL-CMS-Blog-Module

Once the blog is setup, you should be able to access it at "yourdomain.com/blog". As far as creating themes, there is a `views/themes` folder in the blog module which contains a default theme and also where you can setup your custom theme. Additional information about the blog module & theming can be found here http://docs.getfuelcms.com/modules/blog